# Specify a condition-based binary code in constant time

Tags: java, binary

Problem formulation: Given two integer t and l, specify a binary code of length l such that we have bits of value 1 every (t-1) bits in constant time.

For example, given t=3 and l=10, the result is 1001001001.

The solution I can think of is to conducting some shiftings of a binary code of value 1:

```
A1=1 

A2=A1>>3

A3=A1>>(3x2)

result=A1||A2||A3
```

However, this solution is not efficient.

What I want is to solve this problem in constant time.

Comment: I doubt you can do it in "constant" time. At the very least, it will be O(l), no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need something like this :

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int l = 15;
        for(int t = 1; t < 10; ++t) {
            System.out.println(t + " " + l + " => " + toBinString(solve(t, l), l));
        }
    }
    public static String toBinString(int value, int length) {
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            s += (char)('0' + (value >> i & 1));
        return s;
    }
    public static int solve(int t, int l) {
        return ((1 << (l + t - 1)) - 1) / ((1 << t) - 1);
    }
}
```

Output :

> ```
> 1 15 => 111111111111111
> 2 15 => 101010101010101
> 3 15 => 001001001001001
> 4 15 => 001000100010001
> 5 15 => 000010000100001
> 6 15 => 001000001000001
> 7 15 => 100000010000001
> 8 15 => 000000100000001
> 9 15 => 000001000000001
> ```

Comment: I do not fully understand your solution but I think it does not solve the problem in constant time.

Comment: @EricHuang, are you serious? Just look at the function "`solve(int t, int l)`", there is no loops.
"`((1 << (l + t - 1)) - 1) / ((1 << t) - 1)`" is runing as O(1).